# How to limit the amount of characters returned from a field in a Mongo query

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to make a post list page for a blog i am working on and as usual on this page i want to show a piece of the blog content (first 100 characters or so) with a "Read More" button to go to the post detail. I iterate over a cursor that is the result of this query

```
db.posts.find();
```

which gives me the title and body of each post. I was wondering if there was a way to change my mongo query to pull the title and only the first 100 characters of the body field. Thank you.

Comment: use limit so your query will be `db.posts.find().limit(100)` it gives first 100 records if you want sort by order like latest first then sort with limit `db.posts.find().sort({"_id":-1}).limit(100)` or   `db.posts.find().sort({"_id":1}).limit(100)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) operators `$project` and `$substr`

```
db.posts.aggregate(
[
  {
    $project:
      {
        intro: { $substr: [ "$fullText", 0, 100 ] },
        // ...
      }
  } ] )
```

However, I don't know whether this will have good performance characteristics. If not, **using a separate field (e.g., `teaser`) that contains an intro snippet might be a better idea** because you can simply ask MongoDB to not populate the actual text field at all:

```
db.posts.find({}, { "fullText" : 0 });
```

And posts then looks like

```
posts  { 
  fullText : "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet .... ",
  teaser: "Lorem Ipsum!"
}
```

Whether or not the user should be able to modify `intro` or not is then a matter of product design, but it's possible from a tech perspective, at least, and the query is fast.